# Vue 3: Slides blinking when changing a route (vue-splide/Splide js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, splidejs

Version
`0.6.12`

I'm using [vue-splide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@splidejs/vue-splide) (Splide js), `Vue 3` and `vue-router`. I loop through the slides, instide which I have `<ItemCard/>` component, where I have a `router-link` 'View more' that leads to another route when you click on it. When I click on this link, the slides blink, also they align vertically for some reason. You can see a 0.5sec blink on the video I uploaded on `veed.io` - https://www.veed.io/view/ade31623-1112-4032-b240-99f8f0b2a047?sharingWidget=true&panel=share.

What causes this issue? Is this a splide issue or could be something else? If there's a solution, please let me know.

Code:

```
<template>
    <Splide class="splide__track" :options="options" :has-track="false">
        <SplideTrack>
            <SplideSlide
                class="splide__slide"
                v-for="recipe in storeRecipe.data"
                :key="recipe.id">
                <ItemCard :data="recipe" :pending="storeRecipe.pending" />
            </SplideSlide>
        </SplideTrack>
        <div class="splide__pagination">
            <div class="splide__pagination__page is-active" />
        </div>
    </Splide>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Splide, SplideSlide, SplideTrack } from '@splidejs/vue-splide';
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useStoreRecipe } from '@/store/storeRecipe';
import ItemCard from '@/component/ItemCard.vue';

const storeRecipe = useStoreRecipe();

const isActive = ref(true);

// slider setup
const options = {
    arrows: false,
    gap: '2.5rem',
    mediaQuery: 'min',
    breakpoints: {
        320: {
            perPage: 1,
        },
        801: {
            perPage: 2,
        },
        1040: {
            perPage: 3,
        },
    },
};

onMounted(async () => {
    await storeRecipe.loadRecipes();
});
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import '@splidejs/vue-splide/css/core';

.splide__track {
    padding-inline: 1rem;
    margin-inline: auto;
}

@media (width <= $screen-md) {
    .splide__track {
        max-width: 26rem;
    }
}
</style>
```